# How to clear Chrome HSTS-Cache?

Tags: google-chrome, https, hsts

Bg: I am developing a host management tool recently, and I want to realize such a function: auto-delete HSTS cache of chrome-browser by click a btn.
I run [python scripts](https://github.com/craSH/Chrome-STS) to delete HSTS-cache file of chrome. But... after I finished delete that file, I must restart chrome and then this clear-operation works.(Maybe chrome read file and store it in cache?)

Question: So are there some methods to clear hsts-auto? not need to open chrome://net-internals/#hsts , or use my method and not need to restart chrome-browser?

THX~

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option would be to configure a page on your webserver with a Strict-Transport-Security header with max-age=0. Then visit that page through Chrome to clear the HSTS cache.l for that site.

Note some pages preload the HSTS header into Chrome's source code so cannot be cleared. But for sites you own which are not preloaded, above should work.

This this also depends on the "clear page" being served over HTTPS to allow the header to be processed.

Comment: I am a front-end developer and I always need to clear different webpage's HSTS cache because of local-proxy. So I still need find some way to clear cache easily~  thx for your answer

Comment: Then only thing I can suggest is to issue you're own certs for sites you're working on using openssl to create a dummy CA. You'll need to import this "CA" cert into your trust store so any certs issued by it will be accepted by your browser. Then you're good to go and can test over https (and so be a more accurate test as well).